# I need to upload an image with PHP and insert file names in database

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a PHP form that updates records in a database. It looks something like this.

```
//update a record    
$query1 = 'UPDATE mytable SET name="'.$name.'", description="'.$desc.'", 
 img="'.$img.'" WHERE id="'.$id.'" ';

mysqli_query($con,$query);

//get record set
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id="'$id'"';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query2);

echo  '<form action="my-update-page.php" method="post">';

//table heading row
echo '<table width="1000" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">';
  echo  '<tr>';
  echo   '<td>ID</td>';
  echo   '<td>NAME</td>';
  echo   '<td>description</td>';
  echo   '<td>Image</td>';
  echo  '</tr>';

//display data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {


  echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row['id'] . '" />';
  echo  '<tr>';
  echo   '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="'. $row['name'].'" /></td>';
  echo   '<td><textarea name="description">'.$row['description'].'</textarea></td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" size="3" name="img" value="'. $row['img'].'"/>;
  echo   '<a href="upload.php">Upload Image</a></td>';
  echo '</tr>';

  }

//closing tag for table  
echo '</table>';
echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="submit" /></form>';
```

I want my upload.php page to open in a popup where the user can upload the image. I'm pretty sure I can manage doing that. Where I get stuck is after the file is uploaded, I want the popup to close and file name to show in the form input.

Comment: Use ajax to save the data, not post. In the ajax get the file name then send it to the parent window that opened the popup. You can close the popup with `window.close()`.

Comment: Tip for the future: You don't have to encapsulate all of your HTML in PHP. For easier coding, just stop the PHP section using `?>` and write HTML normally: `?><input><tr><td>...<?php...` This will save a lot of headaches related to missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Modify to reflect your names, but window.opener is the link to the other window. At that point, access any elements the same way.

```
window.opener.forms['myform'].elements['fileinput'].value = nameOfFile;

window.close();
```

As the comment above says, use AJAX to do the file post.

Comment: I have a lot to learn. I know a little javascript, but nothing about AJAX. Maybe I'll just have them upload the images on a separate page.